# Livy-Upload JAR in Driver classpath

Tags: livy

I am unable to create livy interactive session with a dependent JAR required in driver-classpath, with the following command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"kind":"pyspark","conf":{"spark.driver.extraClassPath":"/data/XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"}}' -i http://<LIVY_SERVER_IP:PORT>/sessions
```

The JAR file here is present on local driver Path. Also tried using HDFS path in the following manner `hdfs://<NM_IP>:<NM_Port>/data/XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Following are the livy server logs when trying to create interactive session

```
19/08/12 17:26:56 INFO sessions.InteractiveSessionManager: Registering new session 0
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.JobWrapper.cancel(JobWrapper.java:90)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.RSCDriver.shutdown(RSCDriver.java:127)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.RSCDriver.run(RSCDriver.java:356)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.RSCDriverBootstrapper.main(RSCDriverBootstrapper.java:93)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
19/08/12 17:26:58 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

However, when the same JAR is being used in running a python job with batch livy session, it gets successfully completed. Below mentioned is the command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"file": "/data/test.py", "conf": {"spark.driver.extraClassPath":"/data/XXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"}}'  http://<LIVY_SERVER_IP:PORT>/batches
```

The python file `/data/test.py` is present on HDFS path.

I have tried whitelisting the directory path via modifying `livy.conf` file with the following changes `livy.file.local-dir-whitelist = /data/`

Answer (score 0):

Livy Interactive session is 2 Step process. The files need to be there is HDFS while creating the session.

1. Create an Interactive session
2. Use the session ID to execute the statements.

   curl -X POST --data '{"kind": "pyspark", "pyFiles" : ["/some hdfs location/splitter.py"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Requested-By: root"http://localhost:8999/sessions

Please refer:: https://livy.apache.org/examples/

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/191738/invoke-livy-with-pyfiles-attribute.html

Comment: While it is working for pyFiles, my concern is `spark.driver.extraClasspath` that needs to include some JAR. How to provide this JAR and what would be the location while creating a session? Tried using HDFS location, as well as local location at driver machine.

Comment: try with jars option
curl -X POST --data '{"kind": "pyspark", "pyFiles" : ["/some hdfs location/splitter.py"],'jars':['file:///path/to/foo.jar']}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Requested-By: root "http://localhost:8999/sessions

Comment: Tried the following command: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"kind":"pyspark","jars":["file:///XXX.jar"]}}' -i http://<IP>:<PORT>/sessions`, and still no luck. Also, this is an interactive session, so do we really need pyFiles argument?

Comment: I want to run Spark job using Livy interactive session instead of batch, Is it possible to do that ? I have the JAR on local system, and Using livy in standalone.